# Ubuntu 18.04: Can only boot in "Advanced options for Ubuntu" mode

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, gdm

I have a dual-boot with Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10, but I mainly use Ubuntu. When I boot my laptop and click in the default "Ubuntu", the screen goes black and does not boot.

Going to "Advanced options for Ubuntu", I find 4 lines:

-> "Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-180-generic", doesn't boot, is it the same as the default "Ubuntu"?

-> "Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-180-generic (recovery mode)"

-> "Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-177-generic", works correctly!

-> "Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-177-generic (recovery mode)"

What could I do to be able to use the default "Ubuntu" again? Is there any way of selecting the 177 that works as the default one?

I tried the following command but it says that the version does not exist:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-4.15.0-180 linux-headers-4.15.0-180-generic linux-image-4.15.0-180-generic
```

I also tried `dpkg --list | grep linux-image`  and I find many versions but I cannot find the ..180 one.

Comment: It sounds like you have an SSD and it's failing, losing data when it gets powered down. Likely `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdX` (or nvme0n1) will show errors (assuming your disk is in sdX)

Comment: I just realized another simple possibility is that your laptop is executing trim maintenance on your ssd for being off for so long, and that's why it's so slow. It's not that it wasn't booting, but rather when you reinstall grub your disk no longer needs to refresh those sectors. You have to simply wait & let it finish (or factory reset the SSD and install everything again). It can take a long time depending on your disk size. I suspect it's refreshing every cell so that can take an hour or more

Comment: Thanks for the tip @MatiasNGoldberg but I left it running for a day and it did not do anything.

Comment: Might be a video problem.  Do you have any proprietary video drivers, and how were they installed.  Non repository Nvidia drivers is a major cause of the "update broke my computer" syndrome.

Comment: How can I check that? This is a Dell laptop so I don have Nvidia by default